# Is result always 0? Explain

Tags: c

## Beginner C (systems)

```
include <stdio.h>
int main() {

int n1 = -1;
int n2 = 2;

unsigned int u1 = (unsigned int) n1;
unsigned int u2 = (unsigned int) n2;


int result = (n1 < n2) == (-n1 > -n2);
print f("(%d < %d) == (-%d > -%d) evaluates to %d\n", n1, n2, n1, n2, result);


/*question 1 
Is result always 1 (true)?
*/

result = ~n1 + ~n2 == ~(n1 + n2);
printf("(~%d + ~%d) == ~(%d + %d) evaluates to %d\n", n1, n2, n1, n2, result);

return 0;

/*question 1 
Is result always 0(false)?
*/
}
```

I don't get what concept #1 is trying to show but I think #2 basically asks if there is a case where the ~ distributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply both sides of a valid inequality by a negative number, then you must [reverse the order of the inequality](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year9/ch02_linear/12_mult_neg/mult.htm) for it to be valid:

```
(a < b)*-1 -> (-1*a > -1*b)
```

So for question 1, `result` is always *true* or 1:

```
int result = (n1 < n2) == (-n1 > -n2);
```

if  `n1` is less than `n2`, then `-n1` will always be greater than `-n2`, so the equality test is true for that case.

If `n1` is not less than `n2`, then `-n1` will not be greater than `-n2`, so the equality test is also true for that case.  Therefore the equality test is always true.